# Passing the value of a register as a macro argument

Tags: macros, tex-core, registers

I'm looking for a solution to the following problem:

```
\def\m#1{{
   \dimen0=200pt
   \#1=\the#1 % Outputs 200pt rather than 100pt
}}

\dimen0=100pt
\m{\dimen0}
```

**EDIT:**

The code sample above illustrates that passing a register as an argument to a macro could lead to surprising results if the macro happens to use the same register internally.  So I wonder if there is a way to pass the value of a register rather than the register itself.

Comment: `\m{\dimen0}` sets `\dimen0=200pt` so it overrides the `\dimen0=100pt` you wrote before.

Comment: I think you will need to specify what you are actually trying to achieve: perhaps you want to pass the _value_ of a register as the argument?

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, I want to pass the value of a register as an argument to a macro, not the register itself.

Comment: @AngelTsankov OK, could you specify if the argument will always be a register (say either `\dimen<number>` or `\mydimen`), or could be a literal, macro, ... as well

Comment: @JosephWright The problem illustrated in the code sample above is that of passing a "scratchwork" register as an argument to a macro: the macro could use the same register, e.g. for internal calculations.

Comment: I think if you wrote a more verbose question would be great, explain with more details what do you want. In your example just changing the order of the two lines inside the definition of `\#=\the#1` and `\diment0=200pt` gives what you want.

Comment: Well, if you set `\dimen0=200pt` and then ask for `\the\dimen0` you'll get 200pt: why are you surprised? Scratch registers are used this way: you should *never* rely on their value except after setting them to the value you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put expanded value of the register to the macro `\m`. No matter if eTeX is used or isn't, because we needn't to use `\dimexpr`.

```
\def\m#1{{
   \dimen0=200pt
   \#1=#1 % Outputs 200pt rather than 100pt
}}

\dimen0=100pt
\expandafter\m\expandafter{\the\dimen0}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use e-TeX, you can avoid using a register, exploiting the fact that `\dimexpr` is essentially a nameless dimension register:

```
\def\m#1{\expandafter\minner\expandafter{\the\dimexpr#1\relax}}
\def\minner#1{{\dimen0=200pt \#1=#1}}
```

The input `\dimen0=100pt \m{\dimen0}` will produce

> #1=100.0pt

Without e-TeX and `\dimexpr`, the workaround is to reserve a register for this particular purpose:

```
\newdimen\mypersonalandprivateregister
\def\m#1{\mypersonalandprivateregister=#1\relax
  {{\dimen0=200pt \#1=\the\mypersonalandprivateregister}}%
}
```

Of course, the body of `\m` mustn't contain any other assignment to `\mypersonalandprivateregister`.